# Cocoapods resolving version conflicts

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am using a newer version of a library of PureLayout while a pod requires an older version.

```
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `PureLayout (~> 3.0)` required by `Podfile`
- `PureLayout (= 3.0.1)` required by `Podfile.lock`
- `PureLayout (~> 2.0.6)` required by `FPPicker (5.1.0)`
```

Is there a way to separate `FPPicker`'s dependency from that of the rest of the project?

Comment: in your Podfile is the platform version the same as xcode deployment target ?

Comment: @WassimSeifeddine Yes, my platform is `ios, '8.0'` which is the same as my XCode deployment target.

Comment: Okay so i think i know your problem. I think that the version of the pod you're installing is not compatible with the deployment target your using. Check the pod documentation. & please let me know if this solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

If playing around with Podfile doesn't work then u have to separate your dependencies. I don't recommend this way only if you have to. You can download the dependency you want & install it manually into your project. By dragging & dropping the project & linking the libraries